# How to use Drop Table query when migrating from Active Android to ReActive Android

Tags: android, database, reactive

I am migrating my code from Active Android to Reactive Android because Active Android is unsupported in OS version 8.0 and above. I have almost completed all of the commands except the Drop table command.

I executed the below code in Active Android to drop and recreate the existing table.

```
SQLiteUtils.execSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Menu");
SQLiteUtils.execSql(SQLiteUtils.createTableDefinition(Cache.getTableInfo(Menu.class)));
```

Kindly help me use the Drop table command in Reactive Android.

Comment: What is Active Android?

Comment: You mean rxjava?

Comment: What output do you get from executing that code? Does any useful error come up or anything that would be useful?

Comment: @Ridcully. It's a third party library for local Database. Now it stops functioning in OS version 8.0 and above. So, I switched over to Reactive Android.

Comment: @AndreiToader. No.

Comment: @ShaneG. I am searching for DROP table command in Reactive android. I need to implement once I got the command.